# C# System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture does not exist

Tags: c#, multithreading, cultureinfo, currentuiculture

I am developing a `Windows CE 6.0` program with multi-lingual support.
But I am getting an error that `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` does not exist.
How to use `CurrentUICulture`?

Comment: [Using the CurrentUICulture Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441487wx(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Try `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`

Comment: I can't System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture is read only

Comment: "You cannot set current culture programmatically on a device. They are set by the device manufacturer or manually configurable by the device user...", see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5b31f9d(v=vs.90).aspx